# How to change ifthen to allow changes within package or document?

Tags: fontsize, conditionals

I'm trying to change the font size of a table within a thesis. I'm using a template I found online [quthesis](https://github.com/hbristow/quthesis). The style file has an `\ifthen` setup that I don't understand. It seems if the `strict` command is met (default) then the font size can't be changed within a table. What command can I use to change this within just one table? Commands like `\ifrelaxed` and `\strictfalse` don't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{quthesis}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \subfile{1_Intro}
\end{document}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Chapter 1 - Introduction
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[thesis_small.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

    Text that can stay as is.

\begin{table} 
    %   \strictfalse ?? something here
    \caption{Caption.}  \label{Parameters}
    \scriptsize     
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{2.3cm} |} 
        \hline
        { This font needs to be small}
                \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Oh, dear. Like many templates, this one is not well done and will cause you problems. For example, hyperlinks etc. may not work properly as `hyperref` is loaded too soon. It uses font switches which have been obsolete for a few decades, almost certainly introduces spurious spaces, treats font switches as if they took arguments, does weird things with counters, has to be edited if you want to use different fonts and ....

Comment: Nonetheless, the package does not affect the influence of font sizing commands in your example. 'This font needs to be small' is typeset ... small. The rest of the text is typeset larger than small. That is, your code cannot be used to reproduce the problem: the problem is caused by code you've not shown, so all we can say is that the problem is not in `quthesis.sty` or in the code you have shown here.

Comment: Thanks for that! It did take me a long time to get it to compile originally, I had to edit the sty file many times. I think I have fixed the issues and you are right, the table was ok I just hadn't realised. Thanks for your time!